# String split with regex

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I want to take a string according to my regex in java. Suppose i have a String `"R12T12W5P12T5L3"`
. And now i want to have something like this : `myStr[0]="R12T12",myStr[1]="W5P12",myStr[2]=T5L3.` I want to have my regex first a character then a number then again a character and last a number.
How can i do that?

Comment: What is the logic of the split? I dont get it.

Comment: Can you formulate rules on which these matches should be based? It helps with [constructing a regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: i have edited my question   have a look

Comment: Numbers are characters, so I assume you mean you want every sequence of "letter, digits, letter, digits" to be a separate item after the split.  [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s="R12T12W5P12T5L3";
    String regex = "([A-Z]\\d+){2}";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

this will print

```
R12T12
W5P12
T5L3
```

you can put them into a list and convert into array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

All operations from the regex to the string building, in javascript :

```
var str = "R12T12W5P12T5L3";
var result = str.split(/(?=[^\d]){2}/).map(function(v,i,a){
     return i%2 ? a[i-1]+v+'",' : 'myStr['+(i/2)+']="'
}).join('').slice(0,-1);
```

Result :

```
myStr[0]="R12T12",myStr[1]="W5P12",myStr[2]="T5L3"
```